# SQL Server 2012 Performance issue while data load from Biz Talk Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

All of sudden BizTalk load has stated failing in SQL Server which was running for years without any issues.

BizTalk will compile an insert SQL statement from flat file & insert data into SQL Server. It takes only few minutes but recently it started having issues & talking hours. There is nothing changed in code or at the hardware level.

When I clean SQL cached plan before load runs from BizTalk server it finishes without any issues. This is a work around solution for now. I have tried to turn on `optimize for ad hoc workloads` but that didn't help so I turned it off.

I have IDERA Diagnostic Manager for monitoring, but it’s not collecting any data when CPU reaches Over 90% & SQL Server becomes unresponsive. Cannot even run basic DMV's and `sp_whois active` is unable to collect any data. I am seeing SQL recompilation increased since issue started as per IDERA monitoring tool & locking increase too.

SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition dedicated SQL Server.

Min memory set to 14 GB & max set to 28 GB. Total memory on server is 32GB.
It's a virtual server (VM) with 8 CPUs & `max degree of parallelism` set to 4 & `cost threshold for parallelism` set to 50.

Rebuild index job is running as below using Ola Hallengren's script & it finishes in 1 hours or so a normal time.

```
EXECUTE admin.dbo.usp_IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES, -admin',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
```

SQL Server error logs few error since issue started:

> AppDomain 2 (mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].1) is marked for unload
>   due to memory pressure. AppDomain 2
>   (mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].1) unloaded.
>
> 06/20/2016 08:12:15,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 54 06/20/2016 02:13:14,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 128 06/19/2016
>   22:45:59,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 69 06/19/2016 22:03:46,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 96 06/19/2016
>   18:14:35,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 86 06/19/2016 15:18:44,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 43 06/18/2016
>   17:38:06,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 1208
>   avgWriteLatency 45 06/17/2016 07:46:11,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 97 06/16/2016
>   22:46:21,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 26 06/15/2016 10:06:29,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 139 06/15/2016
>   08:02:44,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 42 06/15/2016 07:51:54,spid15s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 19 06/15/2016
>   07:42:21,spid15s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 68 06/13/2016 22:34:08,spid16s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 29 06/12/2016
>   15:18:25,spid15s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 850
>   avgWriteLatency 4 06/11/2016 08:18:26,spid15s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 47 06/08/2016
>   11:23:20,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 54 06/05/2016 22:41:03,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 55 06/05/2016
>   22:33:42,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 24 06/03/2016 05:20:27,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 40 06/03/2016
>   04:32:09,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 99 06/03/2016 04:22:58,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 79 06/03/2016
>   04:19:27,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 162 06/03/2016 03:30:42,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 38 06/03/2016
>   01:04:19,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 66 06/02/2016 22:56:54,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 83 06/02/2016
>   22:51:26,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 40 05/31/2016 22:53:19,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 68 05/31/2016
>   22:40:15,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2320
>   avgWriteLatency 0 05/29/2016 20:56:04,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 86 05/29/2016
>   20:15:08,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 106 05/29/2016 19:33:31,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 46 05/29/2016
>   19:29:10,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 61 05/29/2016 18:55:11,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 77 05/29/2016
>   17:09:56,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 61 05/28/2016 19:03:20,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 511 05/28/2016
>   09:31:48,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 101 05/28/2016 07:54:42,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 63 05/28/2016
>   07:36:40,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 150 05/28/2016 06:04:58,spid14s,Unknown,last target
>   outstanding: 2 avgWriteLatency 78 05/26/2016
>   22:59:37,spid14s,Unknown,last target outstanding: 2
>   avgWriteLatency 106
>
> Error: 8628, Severity: 17, State: 0. A time out occurred while waiting
>   to optimize the query. Rerun the query.
>
> Error: 4014, Severity: 20, State: 10. A fatal error occurred while
>   reading the input stream from the network. The session will be
>   terminated (input error: 10054, output error: 0).

So disk is on SSD will this latency is normal for SSD or may be the OS level it's limiting? & because of that recompilation, network & optimize query error started appearing in SQL Error logs?

Comment: I suspect its the query - Can you post the actual execution plan for the query ? output of `dbcc memorystatus()` in text mode will be helpful when you are experiencing the problem.

Comment: How to get execution plan from SQL servers as all SQL injection happens from biz talk server so how to query that out of from CACHESTORE_SQLPLAN ?